# Can I extract a file from a jar that is 3 directories deep?

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file that has a file named "client.ts" in (when viewing in ZipGenius) "/com/something/messaging". When I do

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("Client.jar");
JarEntry zipFile = jarFile.getJarEntry("client.ts");
```

It can't find the "client.ts" file. If I package the file in "/resources/" instead it can find it. Does `JarFile.getEntry()` only drill down one directory? The javadoc for [`getJarEntry()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getJarEntry(java.lang.String)) simply says: Returns the `ZipEntry` for the given entry name or null if not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full path of the entry within the JAR should work:

```
JarEntry zipFile = jarFile.getJarEntry("com/something/messaging/client.ts");
```

Comment: actually the string should be "com/something/messaging/client.ts"

Comment: Do you know why it works if it's just in the resources/ directory? Must be java just searches down one directory.

Comment: @darrickc.blogspot.com I was fuzzy on that bit. Glad you worked it out.

Comment: Zip (and hence jar) files don't actually have a notion of directories. It's just entry names with slashes. You can even have "/../" within names.